# How to access non-asp <img> tag from code behind?

Tags: asp.net, html, vb.net, code-behind

We're working on a big project and we're stuck a bit here.
I need to access the `<img>`'s from an .ASPX from the code-behind on the PageLoad() 
to assign the right image (attrib src) depending on the value we just collected from the DB from an SQL Query.

We can't use the `runat="server"` attribute to see it server side because we got a bunch of jQuery using the img name tag to work with.

I'm sure there's a way to access and modify the `src` attribute of the images from the code behind view?

Comment: If you don't have runat='server' in the image tag then you won't be able to see it from the code-behind. If you're using jQuery with ASP.NET then you should be injecting the real IDs of ASP.NET entities into the Javascript portions of whatever you're doing.

Comment: Problem is that i'm playing with the IDs to set the img src. For example, one <img> tag has the name T_XXXX_1, then I know that I must set his SRC to Image_1.PNG, etc etc. And it's all dynamic because the user can change the image (and the ID...) real-time via a javascript on the webpage. That causes a problem because if I change them to runat server, i can't control the IDs anymore to inject my value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`Literal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.literalcontrol.aspx) control to output the image element.

You can access the value of the literal to extract (parse out) any information from it and re-write it.

Comment: Can you give me more infos ? I'm pretty new to ASP.NET and Literal controls. How do I change the img's src with the abc123 ID i.e. ? Thanks

Comment: @TommyLeblanc - What exactly do you need more info on? A `Literal` simply renders whatever you set the `Text` property to. You can do some string manipulation on this to reset it. Look at the link I posted for usage examples.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ClientIdMode=Static` property on your image tag. That way you can add the runat=server attribute and you can still access the image tag from your jquery.

Check the following [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid%28v=VS.100%29.aspx#Y0) for more info.

Comment: That won't help with the img name tag, the name can't be altered even with ClientIdMode=Static.

Answer (score 0):

To set the `src` attribute you will have to re-render the control or manipulate by emitting `JavaScript`.